# Set Task's Work Complete Field using values in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I'm using VBA to set each Work Complete field of a Project task using values from the Work Complete column in my Excel sheet.

When I set the Work Complete Field to 100 sometimes it sets the Project task's work complete to 0. This does not occur with any other value.

Here is my code:

```
For Each row In tasksDict.Keys
Dim t As task
' Get unique id in this row
UID = Range("A" & row)
workCompl = Val(Range("F" & row)) * 100 
Debug.Print ("ID: " & UID & "Work complete: ") & workCompl ' This prints out the correct values

Set t = prj.tasks.uniqueID(UID) ' Get task by unique ID

If Not t.Summary Then
    t.SetField FieldID:=188743713, Value:=workCompl ' Set task work complete
End If

Next row
```

Comment: [SetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.setfield) is useful when the field to be set isn't know at run-time. Since you know the field, try setting [PercentWorkComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.percentworkcomplete) directly: `t.PercentWorkComplete = workCompl` rather than coercing it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not setting the work complete field to 100, it is multiplying the existing value in the column F by 100.

```
workCompl = Val(Range("F" & row)) * 100
```

Since you are using the above formula, you will get a 100 only when column F has a value of 1. If your objective is to set everything to 100 then use:

```
workCompl = 100
```

Hope this helps.

Edit1:

Can you try this instead of the if statement you have:

```
If Not t.Summary Then
    projectField = FieldNameToFieldConstant("PercentComplete") 
    t.SetField FieldID:=projectField, Value:=workCompl ' Set task work complete
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this still does not work and I'm having the same issue as before. It seems that 't.SetField FieldID:=188743713, Value:=100' is buggy.

Comment: Are you sure the field id is accurate? if not, try the if statement in the answer

Comment: I'm certain the field id is accurate because it would not work for all the other tasks. Strangely enough it seems that it is failing on three specific tasks whose % work complete fields are supposed to be 100% but they are set as 0%. I tried your if statement but I changed the field name to "PercentWorkComplete" and nothing has changed - same result :(

Comment: When you say it is set to 0%, is it in the excel file or the task?

Comment: After running my code, in MS Project the task is set to 0% but in the Excel file, the value is 100% so it failed to successfully change the % work complete field in MS Project.